# Creating a Converter to take an ID and create an Image in Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, gif, ivalueconverter

I am using a WCF weather service and receiving weather information like ID, Description, and Images.  It returns like this:

```
<WeatherDescription>
    <WeatherID>1</WeatherID>
    <Description>Thunder Storms</Description>
    <PictureURL>
     http://ws.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/Images/thunderstorms.gif
    </PictureURL>
</WeatherDescription>
```

Now in the XAML I am showing my data in a dataGrid as so:

```
<sdk:DataGridTextColumn Header="ID" Binding="{Binding WeatherID}" />
```

The above binding is to another function of the service that returns a 7 day forecast but returns the same weather ID that works with the weather description.  I created an array of all the Weather Descriptions on the code side like so:

```
public partial class MainPage : UserControl
{
    //array of weather descriptions
    private WeatherDescription[] weatherInformation;

    WeatherSoapClient weatherClient = new WeatherSoapClient();

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        weatherClient.GetWeatherInformationCompleted += new EventHandler<GetWeatherInformationCompletedEventArgs>(weatherClient_GetWeatherInformationCompleted);
        weatherClient.GetWeatherInformationAsync();
    }

    void weatherClient_GetWeatherInformationCompleted(object sender, GetWeatherInformationCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        weatherInformation = e.Result;
    }
}
```

1. What I want to do is create a converter that takes the ID from that Column and converts it to an image using the URL supplied in the weather descriptions.
2. I know Silverlight does not support GIF's so I would like to send that image to a handler that would convert it to a JPG.

Being brand new to both Silverlight and C# these are two things that I am really having trouble with.  Thank you for the help in advance! And code snippets are the best help for me since I do not understand a lot of C# yet.

Comment: (sorry for my bad english) The weather service probably only returns a small number of images so maybe you can just download all of them, convert to png and include on your xap and name them like 1.png, 2.png, etc. Now you only need a simple converter to take the ID and find the image... I know is not what you are asking but maybe it can help you to accomplish what you want :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. For the converter, you can do something like this:

   <sdk:DataGrid>

   ```
   <sdk:DataGrid.Resources>
       <local:WeatherIdToImageConverter key="IdToImageConverter" />
   </sdk:DataGrid.Resources>
   ...
       <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn>
          <sdk:CellTemplate>
              <DataTemplate>
                  <Image Source="{Binding WeatherID, Converter={StaticResource IdToImageConverter}}" />
                  ...
   ```
2. In your implementation of the converter, I would use the ImageTools library (http://imagetools.codeplex.com/) to convert between GIF and PNG (PNG will be better quality than JPEG).